# Are there any languages that refer to objects without using pointers?

Tags: pointers, reference

When I create an object in (say) JavaScript, then - as far as I know - I get a reference to that object to pass around.

```js
let myReference = {}
```

The reference is, under the hood, a pointer to a location in memory. ie. the reference itself is a number corresponding to an address in the memory of the running application.

And for convenience, in the case of JavaScript, the underlying pointer is automatically dereferenced, whenever I attempt to read the value of an identifier associated with that reference.

The purpose of this indirection is presumably performance. It is much quicker to copy around a short address, than an object. And keeping an object on the stack might have memory implications.

Are there any languages that do not use pointer indirection for objects, and instead treat objects like primitives?

Comment: C, C++, C# (struct), Go, Rust, and probably many more.

Comment: Thank you. So in these instances, the the object is positioned on the stack?